# how can I get date of the monday of previous week if I have a values like "yyyy-wk" for example 2022-41 using sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, week-number, to-date

so I have a column that has the values like 2021-01,2021-02 and so on till the end of week for year and then 2022-01 and so on
I want to convert this to the date format "yyyy-mm-dd" for the previous monday
how can I do this using sql?

Comment: Is that a ISO year and week, or is your week number based on a different numbering system?

Comment: What does "previous monday" mean? What result do you expect for `2022-01` or `2021-32`? `to_date('2022-14', 'iyyy-iw')` will give you the starting day (Monday) of the (ISO) week 14 in 2022. Is that what you want?